# Solaris Automated install Hard-Drive Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, mbr, solaris

I got two hard disks, one of 40 GB and another one with 1 TB.

The 40 GB has windows 7 installed on it, taking all the space of this hdd.

The 1 TB disk I got few logical and extended partitions; in this order:
1) Windows 8
2) Microsoft Server 2012
3) Empty storage partition
4) Ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin

And some empty extended partitions with non partitioned space as well.

However, I put the Solaris 11 Automated install in my DVD, restarted my pc, and booted from this Solaris DVD, then it started to read parameters of my pc, and suddenly started to download the packages. 
No partitions screen, no way to know what was actually going on (I thought it will show me or AT LEAST select en empty partition or empty space on my second HDD ( 1 TB one)).

Anyway, it started to download packages, and for any reason I stopped the process (it was just starting to download) and after that rebooted my machine.

As I told before, the first 40 GB HDD had windows7 installed on it. Now I can not access this windows 7 installation anymore. I can just access the Ubuntu one, and what's more amusing I can not even see this HDD from system devices in Ubuntu, as i saw on windows 8 rescue system, seems like it's GPT partition right now.

I don't know or i don't think it erased and formatted everything in such a short time.

This automated install just looks for the first disk and erase everything? Being used or not? I don't think so...

I need urgent help with this.

I think that maybe it just overran the MBR or something like that.

Already tried with repair installation from windows 7 DVD but no luck.

Could somebody shed some light upon this?

I hope I've explained myself.

Comment: I reads as if solaris started the installation process over the main drive, without asking. The easiest way to confirm or deny this is by booting from a liveCD (or pendrive) and checking the partitioning of the drives. Your windows installation DVD with <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F10</kbd> and `diskpart` should suffice for this. Please add the output of that to the OP.

Comment: PS: You do not have multiple extended partitions. There should be only one extended partitions. There can be multiple logical partitions in that extended partition.

Comment: I'll check with GPARTED, if doesn't works i'll do the job with diskpart to be sure... And i'll post the output of it as well, thank you!

Comment: Well GPARTED says it is unknown partition system, but when i try to test it, it indeed says there is a NTFS system on it, idk, maybe it's just corrputed, however DISKPART and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> doesn't tells me anything from the Win7 DVD

Comment: I've formatted the HDD :( it was all lost, thanks anyway!